# Roxygen: Shared documentation for arguments shared by multiple functions

Tags: r, roxygen2

I'm developing a package in which multiple different functions have subsets of the same arguments. This means I have a lot of duplication of argument documentation. In many cases these functions can't be logically grouped together, i.e. it doesn't make sense to put them all in the same .Rd file. Is there a way to avoiding this duplication if documentation? I.e. having a master .Rd file whose components can be selectively included in other roxygen blocks?

Comment: Have you played around with `@inheritparams`, as mentioned, e.g. [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html)?

Comment: See also `@template`